# Just switched encryption to "crypt" using PHP but now any password works

Tags: php, mysql, crypt

I am trying to use crypt() in PHP to authenticate users. Here is my code in the login page:

```
$valid = MemberDB::isValidMember($email_address, $password);
if ($valid == TRUE) {
    $_SESSION['is_valid_member'] = TRUE;
    header("Location: ../welcome/");
    } else {
    $login_message = 'log in';
    include('./view/login.php');
    }
```

Here is the function that is supposed to bring back True or False:

```
public static function isValidMember($email_address, $password) {
    $db = Database::getDB();
    $query = "SELECT member_ID, password
              FROM members
              WHERE email_address = :email_address";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':email_address', $email_address);
    $statement->execute();
    $row = $statement->fetch();
    $statement->closeCursor();
    return $row ? crypt($password, $row['password']) : FALSE;
}
```

Currently, no matter what password I enter, it lets me in. When I do a var_dump on $valid, it brings back the 98 char string of the encrypted password so I know that $valid does NOT equal TRUE. Please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
return $row ? crypt($password, $row['password']) : FALSE;
```

with

```
return $row ? ($row['password'] == crypt($password, $row['password'])) : FALSE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Crypt returns a hashed string, not a boolean value. You need to compare that hashed string to the known hash and return if they are the same:

```
return $row ? crypt($password, $row['password']) == $row['password'] : FALSE;
```